# TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not callable

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter

[image: error when trying to print numbers in range(3) using for loop]

I have entered the for loop perfectly, but I still get this error. I even typed this in another online IDE and get my answer. But for some reason, it fails here in Jupyter Notebooks. Please help.

Comment: somewhere not shown you have a statement like `print = z` which makes the print function become invisible in that scope.

Comment: `del print` should resolve the problem

Comment: You could get the real print from the builtins module `import builtins` then you could check `buitins.print is print` (should be True) or maybe `builtins.print(print)` (which should show `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.